# Joomla : How to load template options depending on a specific menu Item

Tags: php, jquery, templates, joomla1.5, menuitem

Hi I am developing a site based on Joomla 1.5 and I wanted to know how can we load varying template options dependiing on a menu item ID.

A good example of what i am looking for is with the Gantry Framework (http://www.gantry-framework.org).

Here you can change template settings on a per menu Item ID basis.

A simple PHP or a jQuery solution will do.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need any scripts to achieve that.

Joomla has a pretty good template system. You have 1 default template and the rest can be used as conditional templates, which will load when specific page is requested (menu item).

See [Joomla's documentation on how to use templates](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aIntroduction_to_Joomla!_templates), look at [how to switch templates section](http://docs.joomla.org/Tutorial%3aIntroduction_to_Joomla!_templates#How_to_switch_templates).

Comment: Hey thanks for posting. I am not an programming expert but could you please elaborate ho it can be achieved? Let us say I have Three menu links namely Link 1, 2 and 3. I have some template options like turn on / off header, on / off footer and so on. I want to have Header & footer on Link 1 and only header on link 2 and only footer on link 3. How do I achieve this? Kindly help.

Comment: Hi, now you are not talking about conditional template... you are talking about conditional modules. You have 3 menu items "item 1", "item 2" and "item 3". In modules you'll have 2 modules: "header" in position top and footer modules in position "footer" (let's say "Custom HTML" type modules). In the Module Manager you'll open the "Header" and change "Menu Assignment" to "Select Menu Item(s)" instead of "All" and holding CTRL key select menu items that will display this module. Do same thing for the footer.

Comment: No that is not what I mean. not modules. Lets say I have some template options in my template like Set the header background to red on link 1 and blue on link 2 and say the sidebar width is 150 on line 1 and 300 on link 2. Like that I want to have these options in the same template and not develop another template with other specifications. This is possible as Gantry and T3 Frameworks are doing so. Being a newbie on programming front, I just cannot figure it how they are doing it.